# If Condition not accepting value in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$BooL = 0
foreach($server in (gc .\ADservers.txt)){
  if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
     Write-host "$Server is able to connect"
     $BooL = 1
     break
  } 
  else {
     write-host "$Server - Failed"
     $BooL = 0
  }
}

If ($BooL = 0) {
   write-host "None of the Servers mentioned are reachable, The Script will quit..!!"
   exit
}

Write-Host "Rest of the Script ... :)"
```

In the above set of code the $BooL value never changes to 1 even the server is able to ping and Also the If ($BooL = 0) not showing the output or exiting the rest of script... Can anybody help me on this..

Comment: Found the answer myself...Was missing double quotes to the $Boo values...Posting for future references..

Answer (score -1):

```
$BooL = "0"
foreach($server in (gc .\ADservers.txt)){
   if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
     Write-host "$Server is able to connect"
     $BooL = "1"
     break
  } 
  else {
     write-host "$Server - Failed"
     $BooL = "0"
  }
}

If ($BooL -eq "0") {
  write-host "None of the Servers mentioned are reachable, The Script will quit..!!"
  exit
}

Write-Host "Rest of the Script ... :)"
```

Comment: This is wrong. By saying `If($BooL = "0")`, you're setting `$BooL` to `0` not testing if that's what it equals. The assignment will always work and return true, so the script will always report the servers are unreachable.

Answer (score -1):

The test for `$bool` in the `if` statement needs to be `if($bool -eq 0)`

But, I don't know why you're not using `$true` or `$false` for this. I'm also unclear as to what your `break` statement is for - do you want to continue as soon as any machine is reachable? There's also no point in resetting `$bool` to `0` in your else, as you've already broken out of the loop otherwise and you already set it to `0` before the loop.

I would recommend changing to:

```
$bool = $false
foreach($server in (gc .\ADservers.txt)){
  if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -Quiet) {
     Write-host "$Server is able to connect"
     $bool = $true
     break
  } 
  else {
     write-host "$Server - Failed"
  }
}

If (!$bool) {
   write-host "None of the Servers mentioned are reachable, The Script will quit..!!"
   exit
}

Write-Host "Rest of the Script ... :)"
```

I would also recommend using a better variable name. `$bool` is very vague and doesn't describe itself - better to call it `$reachable` or something along those lines.